# How to Set Background Image from asset folder in android?

Tags: android

I am facing problem while setting the backGround Image of LinearLayout from asset folder.

```
String filePath="file:///android_asset/images/test.png";
    Drawable d = Drawable.createFromPath(filePath);
    frontTextView.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
```

Can someone help me out.

Comment: What's the problem? Is the app crashing? BTW, why are you using the asset folder instead of `res/drawable` folder?

Comment: It doesn't displaying anything.I can't use res/drawable as I have to dynamically change background of Linearlayout.

Comment: Really, maybe you need asset folder for other purpose but you can change the background dynamically just using the `res/drawable` folder:`setBackgroundResource(R.id.bg1); setBackgroundResource(R.id.bg2)`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

First you create a `Drawable` object from the asset file:

```
Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(getAssets().open(path_in_assets), null);
```

and then set it to some View that only supports Drawables as a background.

Comment: I like it that you made it a single liner :)

Answer (score 8):

As far as I'm aware, [you cannot access assets directly](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/6741c2416bdd3581) like you are trying to. You'll need to use the [AssetManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html) class to get at your data if you want to store it as an asset. [Here's a pretty decent blog post](http://www.wiseandroid.com/post/2010/06/14/Android-Beginners-Intro-to-Resources-and-Assets.aspx) explaining a bit about resources and assets, though the official documentation is also a good resource, of course.

I'll also add, though, that things like background images are typically best stored in `res/drawable` and accessed using the `R.drawable.*` style (the blog post linked above also discusses this) whenever possible. It's not really clear why you need to do it this way from your provided code sample, though, so I suppose that's ultimately your call.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** added create image from InputStream...

I had the similar problem using ImageButton. I figured it out by loading bitmap from assets and using it as image for ImageButton. Probably not a good approach, but is working and solved my problem - unability to have subfolders in drawable dir and not allowed characters in file names.

(Yes, I can use prefix instead of subdir, and rename files to match the pattern (lowercase only and numbers) and I probably will do it later.)

```
InputStream is = null;
try {
  is = this.getResources().getAssets().open("Images/Fruits/Apple.png");
} catch (IOException e) {
  Log.w("EL", e);
}

Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

ImageButton ib2 = (ImageButton) findViewById( R.id.imageButton2);
ib2.setImageBitmap( image);
```

Comment: That's nice but where did the 'image' variable come from? Presumably you get it from the 'is' somehow?

Comment: You can create image from input stream...
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);