# How to get all files from assets folder

Tags: android, resources, assets

I am trying to get all images in my assets folder using the codes below

```
private List<String> getImage()
      {
        /* 设定目前所在路径 */
        List<String> it=new ArrayList<String>();      
        File f=new File("file:///android_asset/");  
        File[] files=f.listFiles();
        Log.d("tag", "读取asset资源");

        /* 将所有文件存入ArrayList中 */
        for(int i=0;i<files.length;i++)
        {
          File file=files[i];
          if(getImageFile(file.getPath()))
            it.add(file.getPath());
        }
        return it;

      }

      private boolean getImageFile(String fName)
      {
        boolean re;

        /* 取得扩展名 */
        String end=fName.substring(fName.lastIndexOf(".")+1,
                      fName.length()).toLowerCase(); 

        /* 按扩展名的类型决定MimeType */
        if(end.equals("jpg")||end.equals("gif")||end.equals("png")
                ||end.equals("jpeg")||end.equals("bmp"))
        {
          re=true;
        }
        else
        {
          re=false;
        }
        return re; 
      }
```

somehow I am not sure about this expression

```
File f=new File("file:///android_asset/");
```

Well, I know that when read a txt file or html file from assets folder you can use this,but would images accept this too?

I have resolve this problem by using the code below

```
private List<String> getImage() throws IOException
      {
        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
        String[] files = assetManager.list("image");   
        List<String> it=Arrays.asList(files);
        return it; 

        }
```

in case somebody else want to know

Comment: +1 for posting your solution, thanks

Comment: +1, the solution posted in this question itself works.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In general, you can use the [AssetManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager) to manage files in your asset folder. In the activity, call [getAssets ()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper#getAssets())  method to get an AssetManager Instance.

EDIT:
you can use the AssetManager to read images like this:

```
AssetManager am=this.getAssets();
        try {
            Bitmap bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(am.open("009.gif"));
            chosenImageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Note that the `BitmapFactory.decodeStream()` method runs on UI thread by default, so the app would get stuck if the image is too large. In that case, you can change the samplesize or start a new thread to do this.

Comment: well,I used Log.d("tag", "get assets" +it); to log if the files in assets folder has been read and logcat print 12-03 14:01:38.780: DEBUG/tag(495): get assets[]
I think there is something wrong with the metod I get those file, any advises? thx

Comment: Actually, I always use the AssetManager to get access to the file inside the asset folder. I remember that the Uri for files in asset folder is "file:///android_asset/", but I don't use or test it. Also, are your images in a sub-directory like /asset/img?

Comment: No,the reason I put all files in List<String> from assets folder and check for mime type is coz I didn't want to use a particular folder for images files,well, it's rare to find Chinese in this website,I am from Beijing, do you have a QQ acount, maybe we can talk there,more convinient.

Comment: Here I find you way may be wrong. See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879416/how-to-set-background-image-from-asset-folder-in-android. You should use the AssetManager to read these files.

Comment: I just test `File img=new File("file:///android_asset/");
  Log.i("INFO", ""+img.listFiles().length+"");` it throws NullPointer Exception.

Comment: Mine too, maybe I'll store the files in sdcard first then read it thx,man

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5552/discussion-between-huang-and-oratis)

Comment: Er,somehow I can't connect to the chat server,sorry

Comment: I googled it and found 
 files = this.getResources().getAssets().list(assetDir);
I think that will do it ,testing

Comment: That's OK. I like to learn on this site. We'll meet again for sure. The AssetManager also has such a funtion to list the files under a dir. Please read the developer document. In most cases, it's a good resource to solve your problem.

Comment: There is a way to get the folder names that are in the assets folder?

Comment: Using an empty string it is possible to get the name of the folders in "assets" (but take a care; because it adds 3 additional folders: images, sounds and webkit).