# upload image on server using post in android is give source file does not exist?

Tags: android, http-post, image-upload

i am using this code for upload image but i have no sd card in tablet i want to upload the image from internal storage how to do this i am trying this code but is always gives source file not found

here is my code for upload image

> default image from internal storage
>
> `int response= uploadFile("/mnt/sdcard/Eiffel.jpg");`

```
 public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {

              String upLoadServerUri = "http://cssthemeclub.com/demo/vixxa_hotel/index.php/login/webchangeimage";
              String fileName = sourceFileUri;
              HttpURLConnection conn = null;
              DataOutputStream dos = null; 
              String lineEnd = "\r\n";
              String twoHyphens = "--";
              String boundary = "*****";
              int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
              byte[] buffer;
              int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
              File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);

              if (!sourceFile.isFile())
              {
               Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File Does not exist");
               return 0;
              }
                  try { // open a URL connection to the Servlet
                   FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
                   URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);
                   conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
                   conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                   conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                   conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
                   conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                   conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                   conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                   conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                   conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName);

                   dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
                   dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                   dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""+ fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
                   dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                   bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); // create a buffer of  maximum size
                   bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                   buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                   // read file and write it into form...
                   bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize); 

                     while (bytesRead > 0) {
                     dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                     bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                     bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                     bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);              
                    }

                   // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
                   dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                   dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                   // Responses from the server (code and message)
                   serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                   String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();
                   Log.e("server response codde",""+serverResponseCode);
                   Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : " + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);
                   if(serverResponseCode == 200)
                   {


                       runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {


                                tv.setText("File Upload Completed.");
                                Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "File Upload Complete.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });               
                   }   

                   //close the streams //
                   fileInputStream.close();
                   dos.flush();
                   dos.close();

              } catch (MalformedURLException ex) { 
                  dialog.dismiss(); 
                  ex.printStackTrace();
                  Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "MalformedURLException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex); 
              } catch (Exception e) {
                  dialog.dismiss(); 
                  e.printStackTrace();
                  Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Exception : " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : " + e.getMessage(), e); 
              }
              dialog.dismiss();      
              return serverResponseCode; 
             }
```

Comment: Whats the value of **sourceFileUri**?

Comment: you can see above the upload function i assign the path of image "/mnt/sdcard/Eiffel.jpg"

Comment: As you said there is no External storage then How is that path `/mnt/sdcard/` ?? First of all check the physical path of that image. Using **ADB** or nay other **File Manager** application. Also Now using `.exist()` function from File class you can check whether file is already exist or not before using it.

Comment: try this                                                           int response= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "Eiffel.jpg"     and give this permission <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this :

```
String imageFilename =  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"Eiffel.jpg";
```

Instead of :

```
String imageFilename =  "/mnt/sdcard/Eiffel.jpg";
```

**EDIT :**

**run this test**

```
File myFile = new File(imageFilename);

if(myFile.exists()){

    Toast.makeText(SimpleTest.this, "<<<< this file exists, it is: "+imageFilename+" >>>>",
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

} else if(!myFile.exists()){

    Toast.makeText(SimpleTest.this, "<<<< this file does not exist >>>> ",
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: i will try your code but is stil gives file does not exist how to solve this now i am put my mobile EXTERNAL SDCARD AND get path but is not working

Comment: yes you are right is show me the file doese not exist but i puted my file in sdcard directory it is compulsory to put the file in particular directory or i can put my image in any foldr or direct root directory

Comment: @AndroidNew you can put on root as well as sub folder, only you have to make sure with path and filename with exact extension.

Comment: @AndroidNew I can use something like this `String imageFilename =  "/sdcard/NewFolder/test1.jpg";` even though there is no external sdcard available. So try with such thing.

Comment: hey can you please tell me how to upload the image from assets instead of sdcard

Comment: @AndroidNew refer this link to access file from the assets folder. [ http://stackoverflow.com/a/8368164/556975 ]. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(URL);

httpPost.setHeader("Authorization", "headerstufs");

String path = PATH TO file;
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

FileEntity f = new FileEntity(new File(path), "image/jpeg");

try {
    httpPost.setEntity(f);
   HttpParams params =  new BasicHttpParams();
    httpPost.setParams(params);
    httpclient.execute(httpPost);
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

make sure to have this in ur manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```