# how can i include powerpoint files in apk?

Tags: android

How can I include powerpoint files in android and how can I access it?
I've searched through google and all I saw was getting files from the SDCARD or the phone itself. 
I want the powerpoint files to be included in the apk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add files to assets folder in the project and get them from assets by using `getAssets()` function. Here is a good [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8368101/how-to-get-all-files-from-assets-folder)

Comment: THANK YOU!...I'm gonna try this :)

Comment: @user2982786 glad to help you. If my answer is right you can tag it as "accepted" :)