# How to set images from assets folder to list view?(using SimpleAdapter)

Tags: java, android, listview, assets, simpleadapter

I've got folder in assets called *images1* with 114 images in it. I need to set them in listView with 2 textViews and 1 imageView. I haven't problems with textViews, but i don't know how to set images from assets to listView.
**I tried:**

```
int ids[] = new int[114];

for (int i = 0; i <ids.length; i++) {//<-------- taking ids of all pictures from images1 in assets-folder
        try {
            String[] images =getAssets().list("images1");
            ArrayList<String> listImages = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(images));
            int imgId = getResourceId(this, listImages.get(i),"images1", getPackageName());
            ids[i] = imgId;
        }
        catch(IOException ex) {}
    }

ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> data = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>(
            questionTexts.length);//<--------filling listView's textViews and imageView
    Map<String, Object> m;
    for (int i = 0; i < questionTexts.length; i++) {
        m = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        m.put(ATTRIBUTE_QUESTION_TEXT, questionTexts[i]);//<-------- textView
        m.put(ATTRIBUTE_ANSWER_TEXT, answerTexts[i]);//<-------- textView
        m.put(ATTRIBUTE_NAME_IMAGE, ids[i]);//<-------- imageView
        data.add(m);
        String[] from = { ATTRIBUTE_QUESTION_TEXT, ATTRIBUTE_ANSWER_TEXT,
                ATTRIBUTE_NAME_IMAGE };
        int[] to = { R.id.listView_item_title, R.id.listView_item_short_description, R.id.listView_image };
        SimpleAdapter sAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, data, R.layout.item,
                from, to);
        lvSimple = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvSimple);
        lvSimple.setAdapter(sAdapter);
    }

public static int getResourceId(Context context,String variableName, String resourceName,
                                String packageName) throws RuntimeException{//<----- this method helps me to get IDs of images from assets/images1
    try{
        return context.getResources().getIdentifier(variableName,resourceName,packageName);
    }catch (Exception e){
        throw new RuntimeException("Error getting resource id");
    }
}
```

**But finally i've got white fields instead my pictures.**
I know how to solve this problem when your pictures are in R.drawable, but how to do it when they are in assets subfolder?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Set Background Image from asset folder in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879416/how-to-set-background-image-from-asset-folder-in-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple Adapter can work only with IDs in drawable-folder or with Uri. But you can use ViewBinder to set image using setImageBitmap method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this.

```
try 
{
    // get input stream
    InputStream ims = getAssets().open("avatar.jpg");
    // load image as Drawable
    Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(ims, null);
    // set image to ImageView
    mImage.setImageDrawable(d);
  ims .close();
}
catch(IOException ex) 
{
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a bitmap by using below code

```
private Bitmap getBitmapFromAssets(String fileName){

    AssetManager am = getAssets();
    InputStream is = null;
    try{
        is = am.open(fileName);
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
    return bitmap;
}
```

You can show bitmap in imageview by using **"Glide"** Here is sample code

```
Glide.with(context)
    .load(Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/fileName"))
    .into(imageView);
```

Comment: but how can i use bitmap in my case ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that this images should be inside `assets/` folder? Why not in `res/drawables/`?

Of course you can load it from assets ;)

To get the list of all files inside asset folder use below code:

```
list = getAssets().list("images1")
```

To load the image from asset you can use below code:

```
fun setImageFromAsset(ImageView view, String filename) { 
    try {
        InputStream is = getAssets().open(filename);
        Drawable drawable = Drawable.createFromStream(is, null);
        view.setImageDrawable(drawable);
    }
    catch(IOException ex) {
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this before i asked my question... And your answer has got mistake. You can't set image to ListView without Adapter